# How to plot multiple histogrames in one plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot all columns (features) in my dataframe in one picture, but separately.
This is example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- mtcars
list <-lapply(1:ncol(mtcars),
              function(col) ggplot2::qplot(mtcars[[col]],
                                           geom = "histogram",
                                           binwidth = 1))

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = list)
```

The plot is good, but name of every feature is missing, it is just "mtcars[[col]]" for all. I tried to used `colnames(data)` instead `mtcars[[col]]`, but it was not successful. Could anybidy help me, how to name every feature in my plot.

Comment: Just as a comment: assinging the outcome of `lapply` to `list` is dangerous as `list` is a built-in command. This practice is best avoided by providing a more unique name to the object you are creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reshaping the data into long format and using `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` instead.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
     gather() %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x=value)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + facet_wrap('key', scales='free')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to loop over the names of your dataset and to make use of the `.data` pronoun from `rlang` which allows to refer to the columns by quoted names:

```r
library(ggplot2)
data <- mtcars
list <-lapply(names(data), function(col) ggplot(data, aes(.data[[col]])) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1))

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = list)
```

[image]